# How to join several validation annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have following annotation to validate password:

```
@Target({FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@NotNull
@Length(min = 8, max = 32)
@Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{8,}$")
public @interface Password {
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

But spring validation does not recognize this rules. I used this annotation as:

```
@Password
private String password;
```

How can I get it without defining `ConstraintValidator` instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use `ConstraintValidator`, you can do it like this:

create Password annotation :

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = PasswordConstraintValidator.class)
@Target({ FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Password {

    String message() default "{propertyPath} is not a valid password";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

then create the PasswordConstraintValidator class :

```
public class PasswordConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Password, String> {

   private final String PASSWORD_PATTERN =
            "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#&()–[{}]:;',?/*~$^+=<>]).{8,20}$";

   private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if(Objects.isNull(value)) {
            return false;
        } 
        if((value.length() < 8) || (value.length() > 32)) {
            return false;
        }
        if(!pattern.matcher(password).matches()){
            return false;
        }

}
```

Then apply it to one of your fields, note that you can also put a custom message:

```
@Password(message = "....")
private String password;

@Password
private String passwd;
```

You can also refactor the if statements each in an appropriate method (to have a clean code): something that will look like this :

```
  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return (notNull(value) && isValidPasswordLength(value) && isValidPasswordValue(value));
     }
```

---

**Update**

since you don't want to use the `ConstraintValidator`, your implementation looks fine, you just need to add `@Valid` on your model so that cascading validation can be performed and include `spring-boot-starter-validation` to make sure that validation api is included and add `@Constraint(validatedBy = {})` on your custom annotation. Here is a **groovy** example here (you can run it with **spring CLI**) :

```
@Grab('spring-boot-starter-validation')

@Grab('lombok')
import lombok.*

@Grab('javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final')
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
import javax.validation.constraints.Size
import javax.validation.Valid
import javax.validation.Constraint
import javax.validation.Payload

import java.lang.annotation.Documented
import java.lang.annotation.Target
import java.lang.annotation.Retention

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME

@RestController 
class TestCompositeAnnotation {

    @PostMapping(value = "/register", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String register(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        return "password " + user.password + " is valid";
    }
}

class User {
    public String username;
    @Password
    public String password;
} 

@Target(value = FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@NotNull
@Constraint(validatedBy = []) // [] is for groovy make sure to replace is with {}
@Size(min = 8, max = 32)
@interface Password {
    String message() default "invalid password";

    Class<?>[] groups() default []; // [] is for groovy make sure to replace is with {}

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default []; // [] is for groovy make sure to replace is with {}
}
```

So when you curl :

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/register -d '{"username": "rsone", "password": "pa3"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

you will get an error validation response :

```
{"timestamp":"2020-11-07T16:43:51.926+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"...","path":"/register"}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I wrote in question "Without instances of `ConstraintValidator`"

Comment: ah sorry, didn't see it, but why you don't want it with a `ConstraintValidator` ?

Comment: Because it is one more excess class with implicit declaration of rules. It came as a surprise to me that I cannot combine these annotations. This is a common practice in Java. For example, the annotation `@Data` in Lombok, which simply combines several others, such as `@Getter`, `@Setter`, `@EqualsAndHashCode` and etc.